# Unable to resolve relative Url containing colon(:) using resolve url

Tags: c#

I'm facing a strange bug.

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/myPage.aspx?param=valueA:valueZ");
```

And it just not work, visibly cause of the ':'.

When I mean does not work I mean on a site like this:

```
http://myMachine/myVirtual/default.aspx
```

If I click on a link containig the code before, i get:

```
http://mymachine/MyVirtual/~/myPage.aspx?param=valueA:valueZ
```

Anyone knows how to make it works ?

thx

Comment: Are ASP pages really supposed to use colons to separate values? Colons typically specify the port (e.g. http://www.website.com:8080/).

Comment: I agree with you. This situation comme from a date time I use and it comes out like this: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. 
That's why I first tried something like this but didn't worh either:
Page.ResolveUrl(Page.Server.UrlEncode("~/myPage.aspx?param=valueA:valueZ"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your ':' with '%3A', not sure if this is the only fix but it is the first thing that jumps out at me.

This is because the : character is a reserved character. For more info on reserved characters you can take a look at [this site](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

Comment: So the question is, why does the methode Resolve Url not "auto-encode" the given parametre string before handling it ?

Comment: Really?  Way to go editing your answer and copying part of my answer without retribution...

Comment: Really, both our answers happen to be the first search result on google when you search 'url encoding'

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `:` character is [reserved](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).  You need to encode it as `%3A`...

Answer (score 0):

For multiple value passing, use this: [ASP QueryString Collection](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp)